# How to measure these black regions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

The image above has been processed to remove its background and increase contrast with `im2bw`. I want to now identify and measure the two elongated black regions at the top and bottom centre of the image. This is the result:

[image]

If I use `imfill(I,'holes')`, one of them does not get identified.

[image]

I would also like to identify the boundaries, so that I can measure the area of these regions and find their respective "weighted centroid".

What I want to achieve is something that allows me to measure an angle between the orientation of the elongated black regions in different frames, as pictured in the sketch below (the red line indicates the position of the top black region in a previous frame).

[image]

Comment: You should post the original image. The thresholded image you post at the top has lost a lot of information compared to the original one, and this analysis can be done much easier on the original image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have added it at the top, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, I'll be using [DIPimage 3](http://www.diplib.org), an image analysis toolbox for MATLAB (disclosure: I'm an author). However, the filters applied are quite simple, it should be no problem implementing this using other toolboxes instead.

The original image is very noisy. Simply thresholding that image leads to a noisy binary image that is very difficult to work with. I'm suggesting you filter the original image to highlight the structures of interest first, before thresholding and measuring.

Because we're interested in detecting lines, we'll use the Laplace of Gaussian filter. It is important to tune the sigma parameter to match the width of the lines to be detected. After applying the Laplace filter, dark lines will appear bright, and bright lines will appear dark. The bright dot in the middle of the image will also be enhanced, but appear dark.

```matlab
img = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LzF3m.png');
img = img{1}; % all three channels of PNG file are identical, take one
out = laplace(img,10);
```

[image: result of Laplace filter]

This image is straight-forward to threshold.

```matlab
out = out > 0.25;
```

[image: result of threshold on Laplace filtered image]

Finally, we'll measure the orientation of these two lines as the angle under which the projection is largest.

```matlab
msr = measure(out,[],'feret');
angle = msr.Feret(:,4)
```

Output (angle in radian, 0 is to the right, pi/2 is down):

```
angle =
   -1.7575
   -1.7714
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I modify the code to allow the input image to come from a video frame, say: `obj = VideoReader('video1.avi');
video= obj.read();
img = video(:,:,:,1);`

Comment: Also, what does the 4 stand for in `msr.Feret`?

Comment: @usumdelphini: you can do `img=video(:,:,1,1);` if it’s from a gray-scale camera. If it’s color, maybe simply take the channel that has least noise, or average the 3 channels together. The `laplace` function in DIPimage can take a standard array as input.

Comment: The Feret measurement feature returns 5 values per object. The 4th value is the angle under which the largest projection is obtained. [Here](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408) I explain the algorithm used, if you’re interested.

Comment: Part of the noise could be removed by removing the background of the whole video. This can be done easily in imagej and then I can input the result into matlab to process as you suggested here. It would be nice to have a procedure that could do the whole process in matlab. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, two things I noticed and would benefit from some clarification. (1) if I input the .png compressed image, things work smoothly as in your example. If I use the original frame from the video (obtained using `VideoReader`), the inner ring (circular area in the middle of the image) doesn't allow for a clean measurement with Feret. What does the png conversion do to the image that highlights the elongated regions?
(2) is there a way to trace (on the image) the lines whose angle with the horizontal Feret measures?

Comment: @usumdelphini: I don’t know what you mean by removing background, but I strongly recommend you don’t do it. There are no pre-processing steps that I can imagine would benefit the algorithm I describe here. Note that the LoG is doing a very strong local averaging (there’s a large Gaussian filter in there after all), which takes care of the noise. Preprocessing might introduce a bias that will not let the LoG properly filter noise.

Comment: @usumdelphini: PNG should not change any of the image data. It may be that data in each frame is sufficiently different that the simplistic threshold I use here doesn’t work everywhere. You could try playing with that threshold value, or you could attach several more frames from your video to the question.

Comment: By removing background I mean that there are parts of the image that are static within the series of frames that make up the whole video. Those could be removed as they do not contain any information needed for the measurements on the dynamic regions.

Comment: @usumdelphini: Yes, you can certainly do that. I would apply the Laplace operator first, then find the regions that change over time, and threshold only in those. The background removal is likely to work better after filtering because of the noise.